# The natural partial order on the set of idempotents in the semigroup of Boolean relation matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, order-theory, idempotents

Let $\mathcal{E}_n$ be the set of idempotents in the semigroup $\mathcal{B}_n$ of $n \times n$ Boolean relation matrices.  The relation $E \leq F$ iff $EF=FE=E$ is called the natural partial order on $\mathcal{E}_n$.

Let $R(A), C(A)$ denote the row space and column space of the matrix $A \in \mathcal{B}_n$.  Then $E \leq F$ iff $R(E) \subseteq R(F)$  and $C(E) \subseteq C(F)$ is a  partial order on $\mathcal{E}_n$.

Is this the same relation as the natural partial order described above?.  In other words, is it true that:

$R(E) \subseteq R(F)$  and $C(E) \subseteq C(F)$ iff  $EF=FE=E$.

I was able to show $EF=FE=E$ implies  $R(E) \subseteq R(F)$  and $C(E) \subseteq C(F)$.

I also checked all the cases for $n \leq 4$.

Can someone give a counter example or a proof of the forward direction in my conjecture above.

Comment: What do you mean by a “boolean relation matrix”? Is it a matrix over $GF(2)$ or merely a real integer $\{0,1\}$-matrix?

Comment: @user 1551.  Good question.  Thanks.  It is neither  a matrix over $GF(2)$ nor a real integer {0,1} matrix.  A Boolean relation matrix is a matrix whose entries are in the two element Boolean algebra where $1 + 1 = 1$.  The $n \times n$ Boolean relation matrices are precisely the adjacency matrices of the binary relations on $\{1,2,...,n\}$.  Matrix multiplication is equivalent to composition of relations.

Comment: @ user 1551.   Yes thank you.  If you post this as an answer I can mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R(E)\subseteq R(F)$, then for each $i$, the $i$-th row of $E$ is equal to $x_i^TF$ for some row vector $x_i^T$. It follows that $E=XF$ for some matrix $X$ and $EF=XF^2=XF=E$. Similarly, $C(E)\subseteq C(F)$ implies that $FE=E$.